# Firebase Analytics events from iOS get error and not showing up

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I trying to use the Firebase Analytics.
on `appdelegate.m`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, calling `[FIRApp configure]` returns the following error:

```
<FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Event origin is too long. The maximum supported length is 32: <ACPEventParam 0x18012br0>: {
    name: "_o"
    string_value: "auto"
}
```

What is Event origin? What modifications do I do? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Firebase Analytics are you using? Can you give more detailed logs before that please?